# Add to a collection where is XElement(s)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm dealing with an XML file that has a very nested structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Stuff>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25367</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25368</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25371</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25372</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25376</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25377</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25381</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25384</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25388</ID>
        </Item>

        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25393</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(102, 0, 94)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
            <Assigned Class="Consumable">
                <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
                <ID>ResourceBeta25238</ID>
            </Assigned>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25394</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(105, 0, 95)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25395</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(103, 0, 92)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
            <Assigned Class="Consumable">
                <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
                <ID>ResourceBeta45232</ID>
            </Assigned>         
        </Item>

    </Stuff>
</Root>
```

Now, I need to add a new element of type `Item` in the `Stuff`

I'm using pure LINQ 2 XML to deal with the file:

```
    public static XElement GetMainSaveFileAsElement()
    {
        if (!UtilityFunctions.CheckFileExistance())
        {
            return null;
        }

        return XElement.Load(Settings.Default.SelectedSaveFilePath);
    }

    // In method...

    var currentSaveFile = UtilityFunctions.GetMainSaveFileAsElement();

    foreach (var oneSquare in oneZone.ZoneSlabs)
    {
        if (oneSquare.SittingResource != null)
        {
            // We have a resource to add
            var targetNewResource = currentSaveFile.Element("Stuff");

            // Can't find any add, create or append method in targetNewResource, it's Nodes(), or Element()
        }
    }
```

I need to add a few `Item`s. `Item` is an XElement.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @GrantWinney `XElement` - that is first line of code

Comment: Themehtod has return sig as `XElement.Load(Settings.Default.SelectedSaveFilePath);` Thats `*XElement*.Load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XElement` has method [XElement.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for adding content as children to element:

```
// var content = new XElement("Item");
targetNewResource.Add(content);
```

Also make sure you are saving updated element back to file.

Comment: I cant' get this Add method. I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @HassanGulzar why you can't get Add method? What is your exact code?

Comment: @HassanGulzar make sure you have typed `Element("Stuff")` instead of `Elements("Stuff")`. Also use debugger to verify type of `targetNewResource` variable

Comment: Ok. I get the Add method now. I just drank a cup off coffee at 10PM and i got the Add() method.